# How inefficient is this templating system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`Users` can be one of 6 different 'types' - Each type will have 12 templates total.

Each template has its own model, with a `belongs_to` relation to the `User` model (`User` model `has_one` of each template, though I'm worried that it'll mean I'll have 72 has one relations on the `user` model)

On creation of a user I will use a case statement to create the templates depending on which user type they are - The template editor will then simply update the templates current database entry.

It's worth also noting the templates vary in editable fields and dynamic content, which is why I have seperate models for each.

Any recommendations on how I could improve this would be awesome, it's driving me crazy at the moment.

Comment: What the actual use case? Is it that users have varying roles or privileges?

Comment: @papirtiger Each user has their own login page and welcome page (redirected to after successful login) - I just need them to be able to select a template on their admin panel and edit certain fields on it (varies from template to template) which will then be shown on their login page.

Comment: Aren't you using [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) by any chance? That way you could override methods in subclasses and thus associate base class only, but have the subclasses instantiated on query.

Comment: So I have one template model and then store each template as a sub-class which can be accessed through the parent models type? If so, how would I control each sub-class having different fields? (For example, one may have three text fields and an image upload where-as another may have 2 text fields, 1 text area and 2 image uploads)

Comment: The underlying table will have to contain all the possible fields in all subclasses, this is therefore viable if there aren't dozens of uncommon fields. Validations in subclasses may be different, and Rails' `render @thing` will deduce the partial name from `to_partial_path` on the model, defined to be something sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution in which you are writing "has_one ..." 72 times in your model.rb file is obviously wrong.

Basically i think you need to add more tables/classes, to handle the relationship between users, "types" and templates.  That's your strategy.

I would make the user "type" (i think "role" is a better word here, and also isn't a reserved word, meaning you will have less problems) into a class.  I would also have a join class/table linking roles to templates in a many-to-many relationship.

I would have a class for templates.

I would actually try to go the opposite way with templates: i would try to bring them back into a simple structure as much as possible.  Any situation where you are making a whole new class for a variation of something is a sign that you've gone in the wrong direction.

Instead, look at what varies between templates, and abstract THOSE ASPECTS out into their own class.  So, if one template has three sections, which are a "foo section", a "bar section" and a "baz section", then make a TemplateSection class, and make a "foo", "bar" and "baz" instance/record. Then have a join table joining Templates to TemplateSections in many-to-many way.  The join table can hold any data which is specific to "the particular way section X is used in template Y".

Basically, whenever something varies, as much as possible try to have the variation held IN DATA rather than in code.  This will require you to model your application carefully, making new classes/tables to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways, depending on the amount of flexibility needed.

Option 1: build everything through ActiveRecord associations

Create a `Template` model and 72 model objects, one for each template. Create a `FieldType` model to represent the different parts a template consists of, such as "title" or "description". Then create a `Field` join model that represents the actual usage of a field by a template:

```
class Template
  has_many :fields
end

class FieldType
  has_many :fields
end

class Field
  belongs_to :template
  belongs_to :field_type
end
```

The `FieldType` model stores all the properties of a field that are identical everywhere - its name, its type (text, numeric, etc). The `Field` model stores all the usage-related properties that differ between templates. An example:

```
login_page = Template.create name: 'Login page'
dashboard  = Template.create name: 'Dashboard'

title_field = FieldType.create name: 'Title',
                               kind: 'text' # careful with reserved words such as 'type'

login_page.fields.create field_type: title_field, required: true
dashboard.fields.create field_type: title_field, required: false
```

We have two pages use the same field called `title`, but on the login page the field is mandatory, while on the dashboard it is not.

What's nice about this is that it plays well within Rails' abilities; you get to use ActiveRecords finders, validations, form helpers, the works.

Option 2: represent your data schemaless

If you use Postgres as your database, you get powerful data types such as JSON, JSONB and Hstore that allow you to store arbitrary data in a single database column:

```
class CreateTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:templates) do |t|
      t.hstore :template_data
  end
end

Template.create template_data: {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 1
  baz: {
   quux: 'kittens'
  }
}
```

This provides the most flexibility. The downside is that you will not get the full-service experience of Rails when it comes to validations, form handling and the like, and you will run into some snags, such as booleans becoming strings.